# Scroll to a div that has a margin-top of 100vh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to scroll to a div that has a margin-top:100vh

The reason why it has this is because it scrolls over a fixed page.

```
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop:$("#sectAbout").offset().top
}, 1000);
```

By the way this is a responsive app, so it would need to work with any size screen.

Comment: Do you still have the problem or does it work?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be working fine to me, please make your question a bit more clear about what is not working.

```js
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop:$("#sectAbout").offset().top
}, 1000);
```

```css
#sectAbout{
background-color:blue;
margin-top:100vh;
height:100vh;
width:100%
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="sectAbout"></section>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop:1200},'50');
```

you can use this i think it's something like this just try this code.

Comment: How would that help when he says it has to be dynamic(responsive)?